# Extract a substring in a Bigquery Column

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have a column in my big query table that I stored as follows:

```
  id           order                            
  <dbl>       <chr>                            
     1 My Order ID: MF212308504-PG5DGHJF
     2 My Order ID: MF202222301-ASJDHASD
     3 My Order ID: MF223408511-PSSDAVQ9
     4 My Order ID: MF765368504-PG59RVQ9
```

I would like to extract a table as follows:

```
  id           order                            
  <dbl>       <chr>                            
     1     MF212308504
     2     MF202222301
     3     MF223408511
     4     MF765368504
```

Meaning, in the column "order", I need to extract:

- Everything after "My Order ID: "
- .. and before the first "-"

It will always be a string of 10 digits / characters.

I usually do it in R - is there a way to do it directly in Big Query?

Answer (score 1):

This works for the data you have provided:

```
select regexp_extract(string_col, ': ([^-]+)-')
```

Comment: How about we want to take value after "-"?  for example in id 1 PG5DGHJF

Answer (score 0):

Another naive approach is

```
SELECT SPLIT(SUBSTR(`order`, 14), '-')[OFFSET(0)]
```

> Everything after "My Order ID: " .. and before the first "-". **It will always be a string of 10 digits / characters.**

I think, you meant to say **11 digits / characters**
So even simpler in your particular case of very statically defined positions

```
SELECT SUBSTR(`order`, 14, 11)
```